Not receiving large json data(more than 1024 size) from Server to Client during 1st time
Not receiving large json data(more than 1024 size) from Server to Client during 1st time.
Scenario:
Step1: Run CoAP Server
Step2: Run CoAP Client (1st time called - Payload size is 1274, not getting full payload buffer)
Step3: Stop CoAP Client
Step4: Run CoAP Client (2nd time called - Payload size is 1274, getting full payload buffer)
When I am running CoAP client for 1st time, I am not getting full buffer, but when I run the same client 2nd time, getting full payload buffer.
Please help to resolve this issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78459599/how-to-receive-large-data-more-than-1024-in-coap-client. Sorry, you're asking the same question again. CoAP's intention is to omit UDP base fragmentation, because that's not reliable. Therefore it uses RFC 7959 blockwise transfer.
